# How do I tell if Vi or Vim is installed on my Linux distribution?

Tags: invocation, linux, version

I use Kubuntu 14.04 with its default installation (bash, Konsole).  I want to learn a powerful, all-keyboard, text editor, and settled on one of these: Vi, Vim, Emacs, (and I'll learn Nano since it's simple).  I have a little experience with the command line: Bash and Python, so I'm ready to add another skill in my pursuit of using Linux without a Windows system.

From Bash, Typing `vim` or `emacs` prompt me to install packages.

Typing `vi` works.  It runs an editor, So I thought it must be Vi.

But the splash screen, if you call it that in Bash, says `VIM Vi Improved` and that it's `Running in Vi compatible mode`. So now I figure it must be Vim.

So which is it and why does typing `vim` in bash not run my editor?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Vim started as a clone of vi and has almost all of the commands and features of the original vi, plus a lot of enhancements. (See `:help design-compatible`.) It can be compiled into one of basically five configurations: tiny, small, normal, big and huge. (See `:help :version`.) It can also be configured at run time to disable the extended features and use only those features found in the original vi. (See `:help 'compatible'`.)

Since it can be made to behave very closely to the original vi, many Linux distributions include it as their `vi`, the basic visual editor found on almost all Unix systems. When you run `vi`, you usually get either the tiny or small version of Vim running in vi-compatible mode. That is why you get the Vim splash screen when you run `vi`.

This vi, though, is not the full-featured Vim that most users want for regular use. Most Linux distributions offer that version of vim, often the huge version, in an optional package such as `vim` or `vim-enhanced`.

Answer (score 10):

Since you're on Ubuntu, verify if Vim is installed by running

```
dpkg -l | grep vim
```

Check the available alternatives to Vi by running

```
update-alternatives --list vi
```

Set your favorite alternative to Vi by running

```
update-alternatives --config vi
```

Comment: That's clear:  I've just got vim-common, vim-runtime and vim-tiny under my default installation of kubuntu 14.04.  "There is only one alternative in link group vi (providing /usr/bin/vi): /usr/bin/vim.tiny "  
Nothing to configure.
I suppose that means I've got vim.tiny, and that's it out of the three (VI, VIM and EMACS)

Comment: @user12711 indeed. If you want `vim` as you'd expect to find, install `vim`, or if you want the GUI frontend as well, one of `vim-gnome`, `vim-gtk` or `vim-athena`. I'd recommend installing one of the latter three, since they have more features compiled in than the one `vim` has (like X11 clipboard support).

Comment: pixel, `update-alternatives --display vi` provides a much nicer view, IMHO.

Answer (score 5):

Quick command to tell if it's vi or vim

```
vi -h
```

this will display the help info in my case :

```
$ vi -h
VIM - Vi IMproved 7.4 (2013 Aug 10, compiled Aug  7 2016 16:03:11)
[... skip other info ...]
```

So here i'm with VIM.

Comment: or use `vi --version` command